# Как правильно остановить приложение?

Tags: ios, swift

Как правильно останавливать приложение когда юзер сворачивает приложение?
У меня такая ситуация. Есть сплеш экран и после него я запрашиваю у юзера разрешение на локацию и после этого запрашиваю разрешение на нотификацию

Так вот если запустить приложение и сразу нажать кнопку Домой, то приложение сворачивается, но в бекграунде продолжает выполнять все те же действия как если его не сворачивать(появляется диалог с запросом первого разрешения потом после него запрос на второе и в логах я вижу всю активность)

Я так понимаю, что в `AppDeligate` нужно отслеживать когда приложение сворачивается и ставить все выполнение на паузу, но не совсем пойму как это сделать.

Как отследить при где находится выполнение программы в момент сворачивания?

Или просто убивать всю активность и потом при открытии приложения проверять где оно было остановлено? Но тогда это нужно делать для всех экранов и остановку выполнения всех экранов как то выносить в AppDeligate(как по мне не совсем гладкое решение)

Или я не так понимаю как это должно работать?

Comment: Где Вы спрашиваете разрешение на локацию и на нотификацию? Это выполняется где то в didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: @VitaliEller нет я это делаю в отдельном классе... Я кстати не уверен, что это правильно, так как согласно туториалам это нужно делать в AppDeligate , но в таком случае запрос будет при запуске приложения, но мне нужно спросить разрешение на втором экране, а не сразу... Поэтому я вынес эти методы в другой класс и использую их там где нужно... Как считаете?

Comment: Ну это нормальное решение, если необходимо спрашивать чуть позже. Я просто пытаюсь понять как вызывается этот метод в момент, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку "Домой". Что происходит в фоне? Реквест? Открытие вью?

Comment: @VitaliEller  путь такой, открывается приложение, запускается splash экран на 2 секунды и через 2 секунды по  Timer открывается следующий экран, при открытии экрана делается запрос на локацию и в клоужере после того как я получаю ответ от юзера по локации я вызываю запрос на нотифткацию... вот так. Но проблема как я описал при запуске на splash экране если свернуть приложение то все действия с запросами разрешений все равно происходят

Comment: Да, теперь понятно. Приложение переходит в состояние background, и таймер не останавливается, вам надо сделать некий метод, который остановит таймер и слушать нотификацию о переходе системы в background. Как только получаете нотификацию, выключить таймер. Тогда все должно работать как надо.

Comment: @VitaliEller ок таймер работает в бекграунде, но он насколько я понимаю работает в бекграунде до тех пор пока не вызовет открытие следующего экрана... Как только следующий экран будет открыт то он уже не должен быть в беке... И плюс ко всему процесс запроса разрешений на локацию и нотификацию я стартую во втором экране во viewDidLoad методе и тогда опять не понятно как viewDidLoad срабатывает если приложение свернуто? Я так понимаю viewDidLoad срабатывает только тогда когда на экране загружено все view полностью, но это же не так

Comment: Нет, viewDidLoad срабатывает сразу как только происходит команда на переход к другому вью. ViewDidAppear срабатывает когда вью уже появилось на экране. Когда приложение уходит в бакграунд оно выполняет код, но не выполняет все что связано с графикой. А спросить разрешение это не графика по сути. Поэтому он и спрашивает. Попробуйте тогда перенести спрос прав в ViewDidAppear, возможно это Вам поможет

Comment: @VitaliEller да) Точно я чет был уверен, что didLoad отвечает за это и забыл про ViewDidAppear это подходит мне) Если опубликуете как ответ я отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `viewDidAppear` вместо `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` срабатывает сразу как только происходит команда на переход к другому вью. `viewDidAppear` срабатывает когда вью уже появилось на экране. Когда приложение уходит в бакграунд оно выполняет код, но не выполняет все что связано с графикой. А спросить разрешение это не графика по сути.